# Phase diagram of SO(5) rotor model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

It was originally a problem from Professor Eugene Demler's problem set.

Consider an SO(5) rotor model:
\begin{align}\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{\chi} \sum_{i,ab}L_{ab}^2(i)-J\sum_{<ij>,a}n_a(i)n_a(j)+g\sum_i(n^2_1+n^2_5-n_2^2-n_3^2-n_4^2)(i).\tag{1}\end{align}

Here $n_a(i)$ describes the SO(5) superspins defined for each lattice site $i$ and $L_{ab}(i)$ are operators of the $SO(5)$ rotations. The operators obey the commutation relations 
\begin{align}[L_{ab}(i),L_{cd}(j)] = -i\delta_{ij}(\delta_{ac}L_{bd}+\delta_{bd}L_{ac}-\delta_{ad}L_{bc}-\delta_{bc}L_{ad}),\end{align} 
\begin{align}[L_{ab}(i),n_c(j)] = -i\delta_{ij}(\delta_{ac}n_b-\delta_{bc}n_{a}),\end{align}
\begin{align}[n_a(i),n_c(j)] = 0.\end{align} 
[1] Discuss the phase diagram of (1).

[2] Calculate the excitation spectrum of (1) in various phase.

Actually, I don't know how to build a phase diagram from a Hamiltonian, could some give some advice or reference.

Comment: This is not an answer, just a meta-comment. Condensed matter physics is largely about the understanding of phases and phase diagrams and excitations and dynamics in various portions of the phase diagram etc. out of a Hamiltonian. In principle, it is pure mathematics to derive these things from a Hamiltonian. In practice, one has to learn (or discover and invent) tons of possible behaviors and they make up whole thick textbooks of the subject. So there's no 10-line recipe that would allow you to draw a phase diagram out of a Hamiltonian, just to be sure. Greetings to Eugene.

Comment: What @Luboš Motl mentions about it being "pure mathematics to derive these things" is generally not true and works only for simple models. Physical intuition and numerical work is often required to describe the phases of a Hamiltonian. For instance, in Laughlin's work on the fractional quantum Hall effect, his wavefunction was an ansatz and was checked via exact diagonalization procedures.